# how to end loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have batch script that does check:

1. create log file with Date and Time format
2. oracle listener check
3. oracle db status check
4. disk space check

```dos
@echo off
set ORACLE_SID=equis01
REM set result_file = %Date:~4,2%.%Date:~7,2%.%Date:~10,4%

set HH=%TIME: =0%
set HH=%HH:~0,2%
set MI=%TIME:~3,2%
set SS=%TIME:~6,2%

REM for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set result_file="%%j"."%%i"."%%k"_%HH%.%MI%.%SS%_"DBXXX".log


if exist %result_file% (
    del %result_file%
)

>%result_file% (

echo Oracle Listener Status:
echo ========================================
echo.
lsnrctl status

echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Oracle Database Status:
echo ========================================
echo.
(
echo @monitoring.sql
) | sqlplus / 

)

echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Disk Space:
echo ========================================
for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims==" %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk where "mediatype='12'" get caption`) do (
call :doit %%i >> "%result_file%"
)

goto :eof


:doit
set driveletter=%1
if {%driveletter%}=={} goto :EOF
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='%driveletter%'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='%driveletter%'" get Size /format:value`) do set Size=%%x
set FreeMB=%FreeSpace:~0,-10%
set SizeMB=%Size:~0,-10%
set /a Percentage=100 * FreeMB / SizeMB
echo %driveletter% %FreeMB% GB out of  %SizeMB% GB Total - %Percentage%%% free 


rem echo exit
for %%a in (*.log*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%result_file%" "%%a"
```

Description of problem:
after running the code - it must archive the log file. 
but the message says:

> ```
> C: 25 GB out of  42 GB Total - 59% free 
> System ERROR:
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
> ERROR: 11.10.2016_17.47.31_DBXXX.log
> Can not open the file as archive
> D: 88 GB out of  107 GB Total - 82% free 
> System ERROR:
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
> ERROR: 11.10.2016_17.47.31_DBXXX.log
> Can not open the file as archive
> E: 415 GB out of  436 GB Total - 95% free 
> System ERROR:
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
> ERROR: 11.10.2016_17.47.31_DBXXX.log
> Can not open the file as archive
> ```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: I would suggest writing your script in PowerShell rather than trying to use a cmd.exe shell script (batch file) because PowerShell has actual language looping constructs that are much clearer and easier to use.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart We are on a programming help forum and the OP is asking help for a `Batch-file` problem. Why don't you tell him to use `Python` like this his code will work under Linux too. The `loops` in `batch`are a very usefull like in Powershell. You just have to learn using it.

Comment: @SachaDee - Just suggesting a better tool. Python may not be a good choice as it is not built-in to Windows. PowerShell (starting with Windows 7) is, and is superior to cmd.exe (particularly in scripting!) in nearly every conceivable way. If you are not familiar with PowerShell, I would definitely encourage you to learn it as your time investment will be richly rewarded.

Comment: I anderstand your point of vue and I'm Ok with it. But what I mean is that there is no `Powershell` TAG in the OP's question so such comment are not very helpful.

Comment: When one asks the best way to remove a small tree branch using a butter knife, IMO it is helpful to suggest that a lopper or hacksaw is a better tool.

Comment: That's not helpful if you don't give a practical solution to the problem.

Comment: We'll agree to disagree. IMO suggesting a better tool is very practical and is better in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

For the `WMIC`part you can simplify your code like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "mediatype=12" get caption ^| findstr ":"') do (
   for /f %%x in ('wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='%%i'" get Size^,FreeSpace ^/format:value ^| findstr [0-9]') do set %%x
   call:next %%i !Freespace:~0,-10! !Size:~0,-10!
)

exit/b

:next
   set /a percentage=(%2 * 100) / %3
   echo %1 - %2 Gb of %3 Gb  [!Percentage!^% Free]
```

Then just add the other element, It will be easier to debug.